# Client Rest Php With GuzzleHttp and Bearer

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, guzzle

Hi im using GuzzleHttp to consume Rest API
My code:

```
try{
 $accessToken="Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

  $request=$client->request('GET', 'https://api.mocaplatform.com/v2/meta/domains/');
 $request->addHeader('Authorization',  $accessToken);
  $query = $request->getQuery();
  $query->set('oauth_token', $accessToken);
  $response = $request->send();
    $response = $response->json();
    return $response;

}
   catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    #guzzle repose for future use
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    print_r($responseBodyAsString);

}
return 'hola';
}
```

But when , I call the function every time show me:

> {"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"Access is denied"}

If I try with postman , its works
[image]

What Im doing wrong?